# Resize a partition, create free space and install another Ubuntu variant in it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Running Kubuntu 18.04.

KDE Partition Manager shows

- a 465GB hard disk at /dev/sda that contains:

  - sda1 /boot/efi 512MB
  - sda2 /boot 488MB
  - sda3 kubuntu-vg 464GB
- kubuntu-vg that contains:

  - ext4 partition at / 461GB size with 100GB free space
  - swap of 4GB

I'll like to carve out a new partition from the free space and install a different variant on it.

I do not mind if I'm not able to boot into my current OS.

Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new logical volume using (it's your `root`):

```
sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n nroot kubuntu-vg
```

Create an other logical volume to use as `home`:

```
sudo lvcreate -L 60G -n nhome kubuntu-vg
```

If you want to use all free space then:

```
sudo lvcreate -l +100%free -n nhome kubuntu-vg
```

Reboot and start an installation.

Use `/dev/sda2` as your boot partition if you don't mind loosing your current OS. Use `/dev/kubuntu-vg/nroot` as your root and `/dev/kubuntu-vg/nhome` as home for new installation.

Do not format other partitions at all, after you have installed the OS, move your files to your new home.

Comment: Just to be sure so that I don't do something stupid, all the commands are executed while I'm booted into my current system. Correct?

Comment: Yeah... adjust the sizes as you wish.

Comment: I am in a similar situation, except I would like to not lose my current OS. Where should my /boot partition go when I do a new install? I already have a /boot just like OP does, outside the vg

Comment: ! ---- I'm not sure if it works, it might screw-up your system ---- ! Partition your drive as mentioned in answer. While installing do not select a `/boot` partition (so it will be placed on `/` root).  DO NOT INSTALL the grub while asked. finish the installation. reboot. boot up your old installation. update the grub from old system. now you should have the option to chose new Ubuntu from grub.